# how to add timestamp to signature using Wss4jSecurityInterceptor / Spring WS

Tags: java, web-services, spring-ws, wss4j

I want to add a timestmap to my signature that expires in 20000 ms.
What do i have to add to my config?

I have my conf as follows:

```html
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="securementActions" value="Signature"/>
    <property name="securementUsername" value="mykey"/>
    <property name="securementPassword" value="123456"/>
    <property name="securementSignatureCrypto">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.support.CryptoFactoryBean">
            <property name="keyStorePassword" value="123456"/>
            <property name="keyStoreLocation" value="classpath:/keystore.jks"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following (source [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html) section 7.3.4.1):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="validationActions" value="Timestamp"/>
    <property name="timestampStrict" value="true"/>
    <property name="timeToLive" value="10"/>
</bean>
```

It seems that the newer versions have the following property name "**securementTimeToLive**" instead of the  timeToLive and it is set by default to 300.